# AngularJS Drirective Template with variables(dynamic template)

Tags: angularjs-directive

Not able to reflect values of the scope variables into 
the template of a directive(dash-board-directive). Please help

On Template I have a button and would like to display button color as blue/black/yellow based on the value of scope.btnAttribData(which is holding values data-theme="a"/data-theme="b"/data-theme="e" etc)

```
/-----------

1)Markup:
Here is how I call my directive:

<div ng-controller="MyDashBoardCtrl">
    <dash-board-directive list-item-value="listItemName" items="btnAttribData" ></navtree>
</div>

Where listItemName, and btnAttribData are the parent scope variables(plz refer DashBoardController item#4 ***)

/--------------------------------------

2) Controller on this div : ng-controller="MyDashBoardCtrl"  as follows

app.controller('MyDashBoardCtrl', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.itemselected = "None";

    $scope.organizations={
        "kind": "TestData",
        "columns":["Row1","Row2","Row3"],
        "rows":[
                    ["Yes","No","No"],
                    ["No","Yes","No"],
                    ["No","No","Yes"]
                ]
    };

    this.setSelected = function (ID) {
        //$scope.itemselected = ID;
        $scope.itemselected = ID.btnValue;
    }
})

/---------------------

3) code on directivce "dash-board-directive" as follows:

app.directive('dashBoardDirective', function ()
{
    return {
        template: '<btn-directive ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" itemselected="itemselected" ></navtree-node>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,        
        scope: {
            items: '=items',  //items holding btnAttribValue ie 
            //btnAttribValue: '=btnAttribData',
            rowItemValue: '=listItemValue',            
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs)
        {        

        }
    };
});

app.directive('btnDirective', function ($compile) 
{
    var btnTemplate = '<button ng-model="tempTheme" >TEST!!!</button>'

    return {
        restrict: 'E',

    require:"^ngController",

        scope: {
            item: "=",
            itemselected: '='
        },        


        compile:function(tElement,tAttrs, transclude)
        {
            console.log("###---In a linking function directive-btnDirective");
                tElement.html(btnTemplate);

            return function(scope, element, attrs)
                scope.classEnable = scope.item.classEnable; //: "class='ui-disabled'"
                scope.tempTheme = scope.item.tempTheme; //: "data-theme=a"
                scope.uiBlockValue = scope.item.uiBlockValue; //: "class='ui-block-a'"



                if ((angular.isDefined(scope.item)) && (scope.item.length > 0)) 
                {
                    var btnElement = $compile('<btnDirective items="item"></navtree>')(scope);
                    elm.append(btnElement);
                }
                scope.itemSelect = function(id){
                    //alert(id);
                    myGreatParentControler.setSelected(id)
                }
        }
    };
});

/---------------
***
4) 
   listItemName, and btnAttribData are the parent 
   scope variable from parent controller "DashBoardController" as follows(which stored into    an scope.listItemName and scope.btnAttribData on a click event 

var app = angular.module('AppDashBoard', [])

app.controller('DashBoardController', function($scope, $window)
{
    $scope.listItemName;
    $scope.listItemRowDataArray;
    $scope.listItemRowDataAttributes={};
    $scope.btnAttribData = new Array(); 

    $scope.listItemData={
        "kind": "TestData",
        "columns":["Row1","Row2","Row3"],
        "rows":[
                    ["Yes","No","No"],
                    ["No","Yes","No"],
                    ["No","No","Yes"]
                ]
    };

$scope.listItemClick = function(inputObj){
        $scope.listItemName = inputObj;
        console.log("### ---  $scope.listItemName = "+inputObj )
        var colData = $scope.listItemData.columns;
        var rowData = $scope.listItemData.rows;     
        var iColDataIndex = colData.indexOf(inputObj);

        var listItemRowData = new Array();

        var arrayUiBlock = new Array();
        arrayUiBlock[0] = "class='ui-block-a'";
        arrayUiBlock[1] = "class='ui-block-b'";
        arrayUiBlock[2] = "class='ui-block-c'";

        uiBlockCtr=0;
        for ( var j = 0; j < rowData[iColDataIndex].length; j++ )
        {
            var colName = inputObj
            var colValue = rowData[iColDataIndex][j]; 
            var tempTheme="";
            var btnId = "btnId_"+colName;
            var isTempThemeBlue=false;
            var classEnable = ""

            //$scope.listItemRowDataArray;
            listItemRowData.push(colValue);


            var buttonAtributes= new Array();

            if(colValue=="Yes")
            {   buttonAtributes['rowItemValue']=inputObj;
                buttonAtributes['btnValue']=colValue;
                buttonAtributes['tempTheme']='data-theme="a"';
                buttonAtributes['isTempThemeBlue']=true;
                buttonAtributes['classEnable']="class='ui-disabled'";
            }
            else
            {
                buttonAtributes['rowItemValue']=inputObj;
                buttonAtributes['btnValue']=colValue;
                buttonAtributes['tempTheme']='data-theme="e"';
                buttonAtributes['isTempThemeBlue']=false;
                buttonAtributes['classEnable']="class='ui-enable'";
            }

            if(uiBlockCtr<3)
            {
                buttonAtributes['uiBlockValue']=arrayUiBlock[uiBlockCtr]
            }
            else
            {   uiBlockCtr=0;
                buttonAtributes['uiBlockValue']=arrayUiBlock[uiBlockCtr]
            }
            uiBlockCtr++;
            $scope.btnAttribData.push(buttonAtributes);
        }
        $scope.listItemRowDataArray=listItemRowData;


    };

  })

/-------------------


5) index.html as follows:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AppDashBoard">
<head>
  <title>Rating Directive Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rating.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/foundation/foundation.min.css"/>

</head>
<body ng-controller="DashBoardController">

    <div data-role="page" id="mainPageId">
        <div data-role="header"  href="" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" >
            <h1>ListVIEW</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"  id="mainPageIdContent" >
            <div>
            <ul data-role="listview" >
                <li ng-repeat="item in listItemData.columns">
                    <a href="#listItemDetailPageId" data-transition="slide" ng-click="listItemClick(item)"> {{item}} </a>
                </li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div data-role="page" id="listItemDetailPageId">
        <div data-role="header"  href="" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" >
            <h1>ListVIEWDetails</h1>
            <a href="#mainPageId" class="ui-btn-right"  data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Back</a>    
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="MyDashBoardCtrl">
            <dash-board-directive list-item-value="listItemName" items="btnAttribData" ></navtree>
        </div>

    </div>  



<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rating.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

/-------------------

6) rating.js as follows;

var app = angular.module('AppDashBoard', [])

app.controller('DashBoardController', function($scope, $window)
{
    $scope.listItemName;
    $scope.listItemRowDataArray;
    $scope.listItemRowDataAttributes={};
    $scope.btnAttribData = new Array(); 

    $scope.listItemData={
        "kind": "TestData",
        "columns":["Row1","Row2","Row3"],
        "rows":[
                    ["Yes","No","No"],
                    ["No","Yes","No"],
                    ["No","No","Yes"]
                ]
    };


    $scope.listItemClick = function(inputObj){
        $scope.listItemName = inputObj;
        console.log("### ---  $scope.listItemName = "+inputObj )
        var colData = $scope.listItemData.columns;
        var rowData = $scope.listItemData.rows;     
        var iColDataIndex = colData.indexOf(inputObj);

        var listItemRowData = new Array();

        var arrayUiBlock = new Array();
        arrayUiBlock[0] = "class='ui-block-a'";
        arrayUiBlock[1] = "class='ui-block-b'";
        arrayUiBlock[2] = "class='ui-block-c'";

        uiBlockCtr=0;
        for ( var j = 0; j < rowData[iColDataIndex].length; j++ )
        {
            var colName = inputObj
            //arrayColName.push(jsonObjColumn[index]);
            var colValue = rowData[iColDataIndex][j]; 
            var tempTheme="";
            var btnId = "btnId_"+colName;
            var isTempThemeBlue=false;
            var classEnable = ""

            //for a listItem(Row1), add buttons value to the array "listItemRowData",then, assign this array to 
            //$scope.listItemRowDataArray;
            listItemRowData.push(colValue);


            var buttonAtributes= new Array();

            if(colValue=="Yes")
            {   buttonAtributes['rowItemValue']=inputObj;
                buttonAtributes['btnValue']=colValue;
                buttonAtributes['tempTheme']='data-theme="a"';
                buttonAtributes['isTempThemeBlue']=true;
                buttonAtributes['classEnable']="class='ui-disabled'";
            }
            else
            {
                buttonAtributes['rowItemValue']=inputObj;
                buttonAtributes['btnValue']=colValue;
                buttonAtributes['tempTheme']='data-theme="e"';
                buttonAtributes['isTempThemeBlue']=false;
                buttonAtributes['classEnable']="class='ui-enable'";
            }

            if(uiBlockCtr<3)
            {
                buttonAtributes['uiBlockValue']=arrayUiBlock[uiBlockCtr]
            }
            else
            {   uiBlockCtr=0;
                buttonAtributes['uiBlockValue']=arrayUiBlock[uiBlockCtr]
            }
            uiBlockCtr++;
            $scope.btnAttribData.push(buttonAtributes);
        }
        console.log("$scope.btnAttribData");
        console.log($scope.btnAttribData)

        $scope.listItemRowDataArray=listItemRowData;
        console.log("$scope.listItemRowDataArray");
        console.log($scope.listItemRowDataArray);
    };

  })

app.controller('MyDashBoardCtrl', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.itemselected = "None";

    $scope.organizations={
        "kind": "TestData",
        "columns":["Row1","Row2","Row3"],
        "rows":[
                    ["Yes","No","No"],
                    ["No","Yes","No"],
                    ["No","No","Yes"]
                ]
    };

    this.setSelected = function (ID) {
        $scope.itemselected = ID.btnValue;
    }
})

app.directive('dashBoardDirective', function ()
{
    return {
        template: '<btn-directive ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" itemselected="itemselected" ></navtree-node>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,      
        scope: {
            items: '=items',  //items holding btnAttribValue ie 
            //btnAttribValue: '=btnAttribData',
            rowItemValue: '=listItemValue',         
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs)
        {       
        }
    };
});

app.directive('btnDirective', function ($compile) 
{

    var btnTemplate = '<button ng-model="tempTheme" >TEST!!!</button>'

    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        require:"^ngController",
        scope: {
            item: "=",
            itemselected: '='
        },        

        //link: function (scope, elm, attrs, myGreatParentControler) {
        compile:function(tElement,tAttrs, transclude)
        {
            console.log("###---In a linking function directive-btnDirective");
                tElement.html(btnTemplate);

            return function(scope, element, attrs)
                scope.classEnable = scope.item.classEnable; //: "class='ui-disabled'"
                scope.tempTheme = scope.item.tempTheme; //: "data-theme=a"
                scope.uiBlockValue = scope.item.uiBlockValue; //: "class='ui-block-a'"

                console.log("item =", scope.classEnable);
                console.log("item =", scope.tempTheme);
                console.log("item =", scope.uiBlockValue);

                if ((angular.isDefined(scope.item)) && (scope.item.length > 0)) 
                {
                    var btnElement = $compile('<btnDirective items="item"></navtree>')(scope);
                    elm.append(btnElement);
                }
                scope.itemSelect = function(id){
                    //alert(id);
                    myGreatParentControler.setSelected(id)
                }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I really all this code necessary ? You have better chance to get an answer, if you show only **relevant** code.

Comment: This is my first post. New to JSFiddle as well. Will post a link on JSFiddle once I manage to get it. Sorry for that...

Comment: link on JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/lgframe/4Bwms/

Comment: JSFiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/lgframe/4Bwms/8/  (was not able to run properly, but do have all code in place)